Implement wind barbs in C# Windows Forms
I am looking for the best way to draw or display wind barbs and I am using C# Windows Forms for my project.
In this project I tried to use ESRI weather fonts. But the challenge I had with it was that I could not place the font in its proper place and its rotation caused confusion.

In the image, I used a font where the end of the character should be at the intersection of the lines, but I could not do this. The image on the side marked as correct is exactly what I want. The end of the font handle is placed on the intersection and does not move by adjusting the angle.
int _rotcount = 0;
int _rotlog = 80;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font fn = new Font("ESRI Weather", 40,FontStyle.Bold);
    string text = ((char)0227).ToString();
    Graphics gr = PnlBase.CreateGraphics();
    GraphicsState st = gr.Save();
    gr.ResetTransform();

    if (_rotcount > 0)
    {
        _rotlog += 10;
        gr.RotateTransform(270);
        _rotcount++;
    }
    else
    {
        _rotlog += 10;
        gr.RotateTransform(180);
        _rotcount++;
    }

    gr.TranslateTransform((float)55, (float)50,MatrixOrder.Append);

    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        gr.DrawString(text, fn, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0, sf);
    }

    gr.Restore(st);
}

Other methods that I searched on the Internet was the use of SVG images, but of course I have not found a free source for these images.
If you have an idea or a solution for me, I will be grateful for your cooperation.

Unrelated to the question, but Graphics is usually captured by the .Paint event and not created using CreateGraphics() in the .Click event.

There are no special pixel in a font that marks center or origin of a character so you could rotate correctly according to that pixel. If its as simple as shown in the example you marked as correct couldn't you just paint the few lines needed yourself? And paint it in the paint event so its sticks. What you do in the button click event will be gone after resizing or minimizing/maximizing the form.

@Ralf The number of shapes that can be drawn is large, of course, if I don't find another solution, it might be more logical to draw the desired shape. Please pay attention to the image I linked, each of these shapes may be selected and placed at a different angle. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmfik_Oqb0_Em8Z4Ryx8XAb2PaeZw2PEM_MA&s

Can you guarantee that for all chars in the font the rotation point is the same in the bottom/left corner?

No! that char show the direction and speed of the wind.They can be any direction from 0 to 359 degrees. I even thought about converting all the characters to a PNG file. But I don't know how true this can be

I meant if the point to rotate around is always the bottom/left corner of the char. If the point is for all char the same there are options to correctly rotate on that fixed point.

I understand now. Yes, all the shapes rotate on the last point (the correct image is on the intersection).. Of course, don't forget that in normal mode, the font is vertical, and in the images sent, they all rotate.
